# How to add a regression head after the fully connected layer in convolutional network using Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to deep learning and Tensorflow and have to learn this topic due to a project I am currently working on. I am using convolutional network to detect and find the location of a single object in the image. I am using the method introduced in [Standford CS231n class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_GfPYLNQank&feature=youtu.be). The lecturer mentioned about connecting a regression head after the fully connected layer in the network to find the location of the object. I know there is `DNNRegressor` in Tensorflow. Should I use this as the regression head?

Before I modified Tensorflow's tutorial on using ConvNet to [recognize handwritten digit](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) for my case. I am not too sure how can I add the regression head to that program so that it can also find a bounding box for the object.

I just had the chance to touch machine learning and deep learning this week, apology if I asked a really silly question, but I really need to find a solution to my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, in order to train a neural network for object localization task, you have to have a data set with localized objects. This answers your question whether you can work with MNIST data set or not. MNIST contains just a class label for each image, so you need to get [another data set](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm). Justin [also talks](https://youtu.be/_GfPYLNQank?t=37m34s) about popular data sets at around 37:34.

The way object localization works is by learning to output 4 values per image, instead of class distribution. This four-valued vector is compared to the ground truth four-valued vector and the loss function is usually L1 or L2 norm of their difference. So in code, *regression head* is an ordinary regression layer, which can be implemented in tensorflow by a simple `tf.reduce_mean` call.

A small yet complete example that performs object localization can be [found here](https://github.com/jazzsaxmafia/Weakly_detector). Also recommend to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45035831/how-can-i-detect-and-localize-object-using-tensorflow-and-convolutional-neural-n).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this problem as well and I found the following part in the [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn).

> Dense (fully connected) layers, which perform classification on the features extracted by the convolutional layers and downsampled by the pooling layers. In a dense layer, every node in the layer is connected to every node in the preceding layer.

Based on this quote, <s>it seems you can't do regression but classification</s>.

**EDIT:** After some research, I found out a way to use a `fully-connected` layer in `tensorflow`.

```
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim

#create your network **net**. 

#In the last step, you should use 
y_prime = slim.fully_connected(net, 1, activation_fn=None, reuse=reuse)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_prime - y)) #L2 norm
lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss)
```

You can add more `fully connected` layers before the last step which can have more nodes.