# How can i detect and localize object using tensorflow and convolutional neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, tflearn

My problem statement is as follows :

" **Object Detection and Localization using Tensorflow and convolutional neural network** "

**What i did ?**

I am done with the cat detection from images using tflearn library.I successfully trained a model using 25000 images of cats and its working fine with good accuracy.

**Current Result :**
[image]

**What i wanted to do?**

If my image consist of two or more than two objects in the same image for example cat and dog together so my result should be 'cat and dog' and apart from this i have to find the **exact location** of these two objects on the image(**bounding box**)

I came across many high level libraries like **darknet** , **SSD** but not able to get the concept behind it.

Please guide me about the approach to solve the problem.

Note : I am using **supervised learning** techniques.

**Expected Result** :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to go about it.

The most straight forward way is to get some suggested bounding boxes using some bounding box suggestion algorithm like selective search and run on each on of the suggestion the classification net that you already trained. This approach is the approach taken by R-CNN.

For more advanced algorithm based on the above approach i suggest you read about Fast-R-CNN and Faster R-CNN.

Look at [Object detection with R-CNN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402760/object-detection-with-r-cnn/43406468#43406468) for some basic explanation.

Darknet and SSD are based on a different approach if you want to undestand them you can read about them on

http://www.cs.unc.edu/~wliu/papers/ssd.pdf
https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/yolo.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Image localization is a complex problem with many different implementations achieving the same result with different efficiency.

There are 2 main types of implementation

-Localize objects with regression

-Single Shot Detectors

Read this https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/content/object_localization_and_detection.html to get a better idea.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar project (detection + localization) on Indian Currencies using PyTorch and ResNet34. Following is the link of my kaggle notebook, hope you find it helpful. I have manually collected images from the internet and made bounding box around them and saved their annotation file (Pascal VOC) using "LabelImg" annotation tool.

https://www.kaggle.com/shweta2407/objectdetection-on-custom-dataset-resnet34